# How to search and get count of special characters for every unique item in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, special-characters

By using pandas dataframe, I am trying to get count of special chars in column using but not getting desired output.

My .tsv file is:[input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOw7H.png)

```
NAME        ID
S. gambu    NNNTYR
S. gambu    RTD:78689
S. gambu    GTT:67878
S. gambu    RTD?78689
G. homos    SFDG\SS234R
G. homos    SFHG#SR234R
G. homos    JHFG:EE345T
G. homos    TYU=TT678R
T. mosus    RTU,YY67ET
T. mosus    TTR%YY67ET
G. ytrty    NaN
```

I am trying to get count for every special characters (:\,#%=?) form 'ID' w.r.t 'NAME' (for every name)(name =4 and special characters = 7) , I am not getting an desired output for every name and special characters present in ID's which are "(:\,#%=?)"

i need count for every special characters for every name. 
i tried, but not getting following desired output.

Desired output is:

```
NAME         :        \          #       ?         %           =          ,

S. gambu  RTD:78689    0         0    RTD?78689    0          0          0        
           GTT:67878                      
           count(2)                    count(1)                                



G. homos     0   SFDG\SS234R  SFHG#SR234R    0       0       TYU=TT678R     0
                  count(1)     count(1)                       count(1)

T. mosus     0       0          0         0    TTR%YY67ET      0    RTU,YY67ET          
                                             count(1)                 count(1)

G. ytrty     NaN    NaN         NaN     NaN      NaN           NaN      NaN  


Total         2      1           1       1          1            1            1
```

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5WYP.png)

~ ~ ~ python
code i tried:

```
pattern1 = [':','#',',','%',]
count= 0
count1 = 0
with open('name.txt') as f:
lines = f.read().splitlines()


for pat in pattern1:
    pattern1 = re.compile(pat)
     for line in lines:
        for i in range(len(df3)):
                if ((df3.loc[i,'NAME'] == line)):
                    if (pattern1.search(df3.loc[i,'ID'])):
                        count = count+1
                    out =str(df3.loc[i,'NAME'])+"\t"+str(df3.loc[i,'ID'])+"\n"
                    print(out)
```

~ ~ ~

for desired output i have attached snap since out it contained more fields.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, if you waste the two minutes of your time to transcribe the results screenshots to markdown text, you improve the odds of having somebody who wastes the five minutes of their time to provide a competent and useful answer.

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]? What have you already done to try to solve this?

Comment: @AMC I have edited my question and also  paste my code which i tried

Comment: i have attached snap since it contained more fields. sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @Twonky thanks! i have edited my qestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC this should do the trick (`df` being your input data frame)

```py
import re
special_chars=r"(:/,#%=@)"

#to take care of nan-s
df=df.fillna("")

for el in special_chars:
    temp_df=df["ID"].str.count(re.escape(el))
    df[el]=np.where(temp_df.gt(0), df["ID"] + " (" + temp_df.astype(int).astype(str) + ")", None)

df2=df.groupby("NAME")[list(special_chars)].agg(lambda x: list(x[~x.isna()]))
```

I'm not completely sure what's your desired output format for values - so I put it into a list...

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

we can use `.str.count`

Note that i've added 3 special chars into `T.  mosus`.

```
data = d="""NAME        ID
S. gambu    NNNTYR
S. gambu    RTD:78689
S. gambu    RTD:78689
S. gambu    RTD:78689
G. homos    SFDG/SS234R
G. homos    SFHG#SR234R
G. homos    JHFG:EE345T
G. homos    TYU=TT678R
T. mosus    RTU@:/YY67ET
G. ytrty    NaN"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep='\s+')
pat = '[(:/,#%\=@)]'
df['count'] = df['ID'].str.count(pat)
```

---

```
print(df)
     NAME            ID  count
S.  gambu        NNNTYR    0.0
S.  gambu     RTD:78689    1.0
S.  gambu     RTD:78689    1.0
S.  gambu     RTD:78689    1.0
G.  homos   SFDG/SS234R    1.0
G.  homos   SFHG#SR234R    1.0
G.  homos   JHFG:EE345T    1.0
G.  homos    TYU=TT678R    1.0
T.  mosus  RTU@:/YY67ET    3.0
G.  ytrty           NaN    NaN
```

Comment: I have edited my question and also paste my code which i tried, i have attached snap since it contained more fields..i need count for every unique name for every special characters please see desired out snap...